# Trouble Installing GriB extension to Geoserver 2.7.1.1

Tags: geoserver, installation, extensions, grib, grib-2

I am trying to add GriB reading capability to my Geoserver distribution (version 2.7.1.1, build date Jun 26, 2015). I am trying to use the plugin archive found at http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.7.x/community-latest/

However, once I include all of the JAR files into .../geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/ and reboot the Geoserver instance, the Web Admin page returns a 503 error.

I have also tried copying all JARs save jettison-1.0.1 (to avoid overwriting the one in the main Geoserver distribution).

Would anyone have any insight why the GriB extension will not install properly, or which version of the extension I should be trying to install for GS 2.7.1.1?

Comment: please look in the log file to find out what is actually failing and add that to your question. In general it is best to match the extension version to the geoserver version exactly.

Comment: Just in case, did you follow the procedure:

-1 stop geoserver
-2 drop the jars
-3 restart?

Moreover can you give more info on the target OS and application server?

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
reproduced and fixed on master and 2.7.x:

[Fix for 2.7.x](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/1155)

You should be able to get a new nightly tomorrow. For the time being I would suggest to download the corresponding [netcdf plugin](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.7.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.7-SNAPSHOT-netcdf-plugin.zip) and take the cdm-4.5.5.jar from it.